# Using a common class for a common set of functionality, by extending a class which extends Activity

Tags: android

I have to show a custom view in all the activities, and I want to do that in one common class.

Suppose I have these three Activities, namely

```
Activity_1

Activity_2

Activity_3
```

and common Activity `MainActivity`.

I want to show a common `xml` in all 3 Activities.

I also need to set the click listeners in one common place so that I need to change in place only if required.

I know it's a pretty much `oops` related question.

This is what i have done:

Activity One:

```
public class ActivityOne extends CommonActivity{


Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(ActivityOne.this,OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

}
```

ActivityOne XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Activity1" />

    <include
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/common" />
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

}
```

MainActivity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button1" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

CommonActivity

```
public class CommonActivity extends Activity{
private Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.common);


    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CommonActivity.this, "Common Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

 }
```

CommonActivity Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Common"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I click common button from Activityone the toast is not showing.
What i have to do more, or what i have done wrong.

Comment: So what _is_ the question?  What are you having troubles with?  What code have you written and what does it do differently from what you want?

Comment: @AleksG updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class which extends `Activity`, and then implement common functionalities there. You can also write abstact methods which you will need to implement when you extend this class 
Ex:

```
 public abstract class MyAbstactActivity  extends Activity{
    //for example for onCreate
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //do your common stuff here and then overwrite it when you need to custumize
    }
    public  abstract doStuff();//Must implement this when you extend MyAbstractClass


    }

   public class MyActivity extends MyAbstactActivity {
    public  abstract doStuff(){//Code}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //do your work as usual.
    //setContentView(R.layout.main)--> is not needed but of course you can change the layout

}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

JAVA HERITAGE !!

Make your childs extends the MainActivity in which you set the layout in oncreate method.

Or use Pager and then swipe.